# How do I take the sum of the digits of a square using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to learning Ruby, and I'm trying to ask the user for an input, square that number, and then return the sum of the digits in the squared number. I'm confused when to use .to_s and .to_i, and I'd also like to accomplish this without using a shortcut.

Here's what I have so far (which doesn't work) :

```
def sqr_digit_sum(n)

  square = (n ** 2).to_s
  no_of_digits = square.size

  sum = 0
  i = 0

  while i < no_of_digits
    sum += square[i].to_i
    i += 1
  end

  puts sum
end
```

I don't get why if I input 9 for a square of 81, square[0] returns 56 instead of 8. Can someone explain this?

Comment: What are you calling a shortcut ?

Comment: I ran that code, as-is, in `irb` and it worked fine. I manually looked at `square[0]` and the value was `8`.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? 1.8?

Comment: Why so many down-votes? This is a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you’re using Ruby 1.8, where [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with a Fixnum argument (e.g. `'8'[0]`) returns the decimal ASCII character value. Which for `'8'` is `56`. Since this is already a Fixnum, calling `to_i` on it has no effect. You should instead pass an index and length to `[]`:

```
string = '81'
string[0, 1]  #=> "8"
string[1, 1]  #=> "1"
```

If you want all the characters in an array, though, you should use [`chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-chars)/[`each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-each_char):

```
string = '81'
string.chars.to_a  #=> ["8", "1"]
string.chars.to_a.map { |char| char.to_i }  #=> [8, 1]
```

This makes implementing what you want fairly straightforward using the above and [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
n = 9
(n ** 2).to_s.chars.to_a.map { |char| char.to_i }.reduce(0, :+)  #=> 9
```

Ultimately, though, **you should upgrade to Ruby 2.0 (or at least 1.9.2+) as soon as possible** as 1.8 is no longer supported and receives no security updates.

Comment: Good catch. Not a lot of people know about this bug. =) ...or is it a feature?

Comment: @mohawkjohn Was a feature, but then (rightfully) rethought. Perhaps even less known is Ruby’s character literal (`?x`) which evaluates to the same value `'x'[0]` returns, regardless of Ruby version.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just started learning Ruby a couple days ago so I apologize for my naivete

Comment: I'm not sure why you got down-voted other than apparently all the down-voters weren't aware of this feature. =/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
def sqr_digit_sum(n)
  square = (n ** 2)
  puts square.to_s.split(//).inject(0) { |sum, number_as_string| number_as_string.to_i + sum }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code [works just fine](http://ideone.com/Zro1OW). Also, for the following code, [the result](http://ideone.com/YnOmyG) is `8` as expected:

```
n = 9 
square = (n ** 2).to_s[0]
puts square
```

Finally, may I suggest to refactor your code as:

```
def sqr_digit_sum(n)
  sum = 0
  (n ** 2).to_s.each_char { |c| sum += c.to_i }
  puts sum
end
```

you don't really need a `while` loop there.

Comment: @mohawkjohn, but [it does](http://ideone.com/METM7R) in 1.9. No one ever said anything about being compatible with ancient versions of Ruby.

Comment: @Jeffery Not explicitly, but there’s only one valid reason `'81'[0]` would return `56`: Ruby 1.8 (or earlier) is being used.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, I always assume the latest stable version of a language is used, unless specified otherwise. There's no such specification in the question above. Therefore this might not be a valid answer for the OP, but sure as hell it is a valid answer for future visitors.

Comment: If other people are searching for this exact problem, it's probably because they're beginners accidentally using 1.8. Come on -- beginners! They don't know what version they're using.